# In Excel, have a conditional copy of a column, from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, copy, conditional-statements

I have an excel file with two columns

```
project1  project2
a1        a2
b1        b2
c1        c2
          d2
```

I create on the side a list of possible projects using

```
Data>Validation> list of "project1 project2"
```

The user will pick a project from the dropdown menu,

[image: choosingProject]

but how can I do that the column (a* b* c*) automatically appear below the chosen project? See below an example I what I would like

[image: whatiwant]

I could use IF() for each cell, but I don't want to depend on the number of rows.

Comment: Can you explain what you're after? When a user selects, say, `b1`, `c2`, from the two data validations, what do you want to populate? Could you perhaps post a sample table of expected output?

Comment: I added some screenshots to my question, in fact I just want to execute a "conditional copy" of a column, and not having to give a formula for each cell in a row

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(INDEX(A:C,ROW(2:2),MATCH($E$1,$1:$1,0))<>0,INDEX(A:C,ROW(2:2),MATCH($E$1,$1:$1,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: well, I still need to propagate the formula down along the column. Is'nt there a way like (if( E1 == "project2" ) print( B from 2 until empty ) ?

Comment: Not with formulas in Excel.  You will need vba tied to a Worksheet_Change event. @XavierPrudent

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible answer using named ranges:

First, create named ranges:  select the data in columns A and B, including the project titles > Formulas > Create from Selection > Top Row (make sure "left column" is NOT selected)

Once you have those, simply put this formula into cell E2 and drag down to the bottom of your data set:

```
=iferror(indirect($E$2),"")
```

You can take away the "iferror" logic if you'd like - you'll just get errors where the indirect formula extends past the actual data set.